# "publish" to local maven repo creates only scaladoc jars?

Tags: sbt

I'm using sbt 0.13.0 and Scala 2.10.3

I wanted to publish an artifact to my local maven repo so I added the following to `build.sbt`:

```
publishMavenStyle := true

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))

artifactName := { 
  (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
    artifact.name + "-" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

When I use `publish` cmd jars are created in my home .m2 directory but there are of the same content meaning they only contain scaladocs - only html, css and js files.

This is my second time I'm publishing my artifact in this project. Last time it worked perfectly. Most of the classes changed their packages, can this be the reason, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `artifactName` and it should work fine again.

Why do you redefine it (as it now breaks `publish`)? What's the initial goal?

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, np.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
[sbt-0-13-1]> help artifactName
Function that produces the artifact name from its definition.
[sbt-0-13-1]> inspect artifactName
[info] Setting: scala.Function3[sbt.ScalaVersion, sbt.ModuleID, sbt.Artifact, java.lang.String] = <function3>
[info] Description:
[info]  Function that produces the artifact name from its definition.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:artifactName
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:533
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:makePom::artifactPath
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:artifactName
[info]  {.}/*:artifactName
[info]  */*:artifactName
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:artifactName
```

See how the default implementation is defined in [sbt.Artifact](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Artifact.scala#L57).

Comment: Thanks @Jacek, it worked!

Now I'm wondering why a function that returns String that is used to generate filenames can change the overall behavior so dramatically?

Comment: Ohh You've asked why I wanted to change the name. I don't remember :)

This jar is used by my colleagues that don't touch Scala so in front of it there is a plain java interface. Naming had something to do with this but I really don't remember what was the actual cause.